# Encoding error in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, encoding, utf-8

I have run my program and everything works great.  I am now trying to write some tests and I keep getting this error:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

I am not using any weird characters to my knowledge.  I dont even know where to begin with this error.  I tried adding these two lines to the environment.rb file:

```
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
```

and that did not help.  Here is the test I am trying to run:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "should require all fields" do
    u = User.new
    assert_false u.valid?
  end
end
```

here is my users.yml file:

```
one:
  name: MyString
  password: MyString

two:
  name: MyString
  password: MyString

<% (1..5).each do |i| %>
  user_<%= i %>:
    name: user_<%= i %>
    password: user_<%= i %>
<% end %>
```

here is my stack trace:

```
Creating sqlite :memory: database
-- create_table("comment_votes", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0021s
-- create_table("comments", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0013s
-- add_index("comments", ["post_id"], {:name=>"index_comments_on_post_id"})
   -> 0.0005s
-- create_table("posts", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0015s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0013s
-- create_table("votes", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0010s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0009s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20111005200722, ["db/migrate"])
   -> 0.0013s

Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications

Test suite finished: 0.058747 seconds

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your passwords salted?  And does the salt, by any chance, use random bytes that may not conform to UTF-8 or US-ASCII?  This has caught me out before.  I had to `force_encoding("BINARY")` on my password salts.

Comment: Well, I used DataMapper, not ActiveRecord, so in my case it was actually a bug in DM that I [submitted a patch](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/pull/141) for.  Maybe try defining `password_salt=` (or whatever the field is) and `password_salt` and do it there?

Comment: Can you post your password salting and checking logic?  I can probably help more then.

Comment: this is where I generate salt:   def generate_salt
    self.salt = self.object_id.to_s + rand.to_s
  end

Comment: I am using SHA2 to encrypt the password

Comment: Ah, that shouldn't matter, since that's valid UTF-8 anyway.  The problem must be coming from somewhere else.  Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Creating sqlite :memory: database
-- create_table("comment_votes", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0399s
-- create_table("comments", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0016s
-- add_index("comments", ["post_id"], {:name=>"index_comments_on_post_id"})
   -> 0.0006s
-- create_table("posts", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0025s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0014s
-- create_table("votes", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0011s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0009s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20111005200722, ["db/migrate"])
   -> 0.0013s

Comment: 1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications

Test suite finished: 0.059387 seconds

Comment: between those two was my error.  Could not post the whole thing due to length restrictions